# Close context menu on click outside

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-context

I have problem with context menu. I have got:

```
@Override
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, COPY, Menu.NONE, "Copy")
        .setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, NOTE, Menu.NONE, "Note")
    .setAlphabeticShortcut('n');
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, PAGE, Menu.NONE, "Page")
    .setAlphabeticShortcut('p');

  }
```

and I want close it when I touch screen outside ContextMenu. Please help me!

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is any direct method to close the `ContextMenu` on outside click. But if you want that functionality then you may use a `Dialog` instead of a `ContextMenu` and then using `dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` you can close the dialog on outside click.

Comment: I know it, but I want ContextMenu :( I will use it eventually.